# On OSX, how do I gradient fill a path stroke?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics

Using the plethora of drawing functions in Cocoa or Quartz it's rather easy to draw paths, and fill them using a gradient. I can't seem to find an acceptable way however, to 'stroke'-draw a path with a line width of a few pixels and fill this stroke using a gradient. How is this done?

Edit: Apparently the question wasn't clear enough. Thanks for the responses so far, but I already figured that out. What I want to do is this:

[image: squares]
<sub>(source: [emle.nl](http://emle.nl/forumpics/misc/squares.png))</sub>

The left square is NSGradient drawn in a path followed by a path stroke message. The right is what I want to do; I want to fill the stroke using the gradient.

Comment: The link no longer works

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you convert the `NSBezierPath` to a `CGPath`, you can use the `CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath()` method to retrieve a path that is the outline of the stroked path. Graham Cox's excellent **[GCDrawKit](http://apptree.net/drawkit.htm)** has a `-strokedPath` category method on `NSBezierPath` that will do this for you without needing to drop down to Core Graphics.

Once you have the outlined path, you can fill that path with an `NSGradient`.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you :)

Thanks for the link to drawkit too, it looks very nice.

Comment: I had problems making this work- my gradient filled the entire clipped area, rather than the path (perhaps this had to do with doing clipping as well).  I ended up drawing one shape that was simply the outline of the border, clipping to that path, and then using the gradient fill, and that worked best.

Answer (score 14):

> I can't seem to find an acceptable way however, to 'stroke'-draw a path with a line width of a few pixels and fill this stroke using a gradient. How is this done?

[Original answer replaced with the following]

Ah, I see. You want to apply the gradient to the stroke.

To do that, you use a blend mode. I explained how to do this in an answer on [another question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366571/applying-a-texture-to-stroke-a-cgcontextstrokepath) Here's the list of steps, adapted to your goal:

1. Begin a [transparency layer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_trans_layers/dq_trans_layers.html).
2. Stroke the path with any non-transparent color.
3. [Set the blend mode](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetBlendMode) to [source in](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCGBlendModeSourceIn).
4. Draw the gradient.
5. End the transparency layer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's however, not what I try to achieve. I've clarified the question a bit.

Comment: Emiel: Ah, I see. I've replaced the previous contents of my answer with a new answer.

Answer (score 9):

According to Peter Hosey's answer I've managed to do a simple gradient curve, which looks like this:

[image: Gradient Curve Image]

I've done this in drawRect(_:) method of UIView class by writing the code below:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer (context, nil)
    let path = createCurvePath()
    UIColor.blueColor().setStroke()
    path.stroke()
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .SourceIn)

    let colors          = [UIColor.blueColor().CGColor, UIColor.redColor().CGColor]
    let colorSpace      = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let colorLocations  :[CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]
    let gradient        = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, colors, colorLocations)
    let startPoint      = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: rect.size.height / 2)
    let endPoint        = CGPoint(x: rect.size.width, y: rect.size.height / 2)

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, CGGradientDrawingOptions.DrawsBeforeStartLocation)
    CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context)
}
```

Function createCurvePath() returns an UIBezierPath object. I've also set path.lineWidth to 5 points.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to make the path be blue in the beginning and red in the end, but f.e. bend the curve back to where it started?