# Gradient along MKPolyLineView ( MKPolylineRenderer )

Tags: ios, iphone, core-graphics, mkpolyline

I'd like to apply a gradient on a polyline view depending on some conditions like speed. 
I was able to subclass `MKPolyLineRenderer` to draw with custom stroke and fill, but only with the same color along the path.

I saw other similar questions like : [Draw segments from a circle or donut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866179/draw-segments-from-a-circle-or-donut/15868472)  or [On OSX, how do I gradient fill a path stroke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737973/on-osx-how-do-i-gradient-fill-a-path-stroke) , but it is not exactly what I'd want. 
If I understand correctly, a path like below couldn't be filled with these methods. At least not treated as a whole.

[image]

A very similar question is [Gradient Polyline with MapKit ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682688/gradient-mkoverlay-on-mkmapview-iphone). But it adds an overlay for each segment between the points, which I think isn't too efficient.

Is this the only possible way ? ( I'd need to draw hundreds or maybe thousands of these segments ... )  How can this be achieved easily ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the original answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159374/2606068

you can find the demo here https://github.com/wdanxna/GradientPolyline

and some improvement tips provided by @Templar is:

- prepare the path directly in the init.
- check also for CGRectContains, not only for intersection.

thanks man! :p