# Draw polygon with color per vertex

Tags: ios, mkmapview, core-graphics, polygon, gradient

I am wondering if there is a way to draw a polygon on top of a MKMapView where each vertex in the polygon could potentially have a different color.  The triangles of the polygon would correctly blend the colors together when rendered.

I know I can do this with OpenGL, but I would like to try to use CoreGraphics or a drawing function of MapKit first, as I don't know how well OpenGL works on top of a MKMapView.

I know there is support to fill a polyline with a gradient.  Is there a similar way to fill a polygon/triangle with multiple gradients to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: You'll need to implement a custom MKOverlayRenderer.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682688/gradient-polyline-with-mapkit-ios, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247313/gradient-along-mkpolylineview-mkpolylinerenderer