# Gradient as circle stroke color in CAShapeLayer

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-graphics, cashapelayer

```
    CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 100) cornerRadius:50].CGPath;

    // Configure the apperence of the circle
    circle.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    circle.strokeColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    circle.lineWidth = 1.8;
    circle.lineDashPattern = @[@6, @3];
    // Add to parent layer
    [cell.layer addSublayer:circle];
```

I am using this code to draw a circle. Now, I want to use a gradient as stroke color. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [On OSX, how do I gradient fill a path stroke?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737973/on-osx-how-do-i-gradient-fill-a-path-stroke)

Comment: @Dima I couldn't figure out how it would work.